# Can't debug Azure Applications with v1.5 of SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

After upgrading to Azure 1.5, I can't debug Azure applications from VS 2010.  When I press F5, I get the following error:

"Could not load file or assembly 'DevFabric.Contracts, Version=0.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

The application runs fine when it's deployed. It was working before I installed 1.5.

Comment: I have the same problem instead of I install Azure SDK 1.5 on a fresh install of Windows 7 x64. It works fine for 2/3 days and tomorow I have the same error. Do you have a solution ? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing yet. I've opened a ticket with Microsoft Product Support. I'll update this post if I get a resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer has been found in this thread : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/f3a0dd74-93fc-4b31-acd1-64362b8976e5

*EDIT: from MSDN forums:

Is the DevFabric.contracts.dll in your C:\program files\windows azure sdk\v1.5\bin\devfabric folder?

If so, try to moving it to the C:\program files\windows azure sdk\v1.5\bin folder and see if that solves the problem?